# Copy files from one folder to another with Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

```
new AntBuilder().copy(todir: destinationDir) {
    fileset(dir: sourceDir)
}
```

i have used above code to copy a file from source to destination folder.

it was working fine with grails 2.3.0 now updated grails to 2.3.4 ,now its not working in production environment.

Now getting the following error 
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException"

Comment: What do you mean 'not working'?  Errors?  Just does nothing?  WHere does `webAppPath` come from?

Comment: Do you definitely have a dependency on Ant?  I'm pretty sure there isn't one provided by default.

Comment: webAppPath is assigned no problem in that.it was working before updating the version now getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException" as error

Comment: Ian, any dependency file missing in this release ?! can you people please suggest another way to move a files from one directory to another in groovy ?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're running on JDK7, you can use [java.nio.file.Files.copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) method

Comment: i am using JDK7 EE ,imported the classes but getting 'Cannot Resolve the symbol "Path"..

Comment: getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.file.FileSystems after hosted it into Aws !!

Answer (score 1):

I am using Grails 2.4.3 and Java 1.6. In my case the solution was added the includes option like this:

```
new AntBuilder().copy(todir: destinationDir) {
    fileset(dir: sourceDir, includes: "**")
}
```