# How to copy files in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I need to copy a file in Groovy and saw some ways to achieve it on the web:

1

```
new AntBuilder().copy( file:"$sourceFile.canonicalPath", 
                           tofile:"$destFile.canonicalPath")
```

2

```
command = ["sh", "-c", "cp src/*.txt dst/"]
Runtime.getRuntime().exec((String[]) command.toArray())
```

3

```
 destination.withDataOutputStream { os->  
    source.withDataInputStream { is->  
       os << is  
    }  
 }
```

4

```
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
Files.copy(Paths.get(a), Paths.get(b))
```

The 4th way seems cleanest to me as I am not sure how good is it to use AntBuilder and how heavy it is, I saw some people reporting issues with Groovy version change. 
2nd way is OS dependent, 3rd might not be efficient.

Is there something in Groovy to just copy files like in the 4th statement or should I just use Java for it?

Comment: The question itself is good answer for "How to copy files in groovy" :)

Comment: I got `unable to resolve class java.nio.files.Paths` when using this in Gradle. I use `import java.nio.*` and `import java.nio.file.*` instead.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun is right, it's [`java.nio.file.Paths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you have Java 7, I would definitely go with

```
Path source = ...
Path target = ...
Files.copy(source, target)
```

With the [java.nio.file.Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) class, it can work with symbolic and hard links. From [java.nio.file.Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html):

> This class consists exclusively of static methods that operate on
>   files, directories, or other types of files. In most cases, the
>   methods defined here ***will delegate to the associated file system
>   provider to perform the file operations***.

Just as references:

[Copy files from one folder to another with Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527719/copy-files-from-one-folder-to-another-with-groovy)

http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/view.groovy?id=8001

My second option would be the `ant` task with `AntBuilder`.

Comment: That is Java not Groovy. So that is not the answer then. See this link for groovy answer. http://grails.asia/groovy-copy-file-examples

Comment: Being both on top of the JVM, and being groovy somehow a superset of Java (GDK, etc), IMHO the "java not groovy" is pointless. The link basically shows other answers of this question, and quoting it: *"Note that this can be potentially slow and memory hungry, as this code loads the entire file to memory before copying"*. That is quite an issue, so I will say again that it is better to delegate to the underlying file system although there are other *groovier* solutions. Anyway, thanks for commenting on your downvote.

Comment: How do you create a `Path` from a `String`?

Comment: @Arjang also that link is now broken

Comment: Copy file with groovy is described here.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_file_io.htm

Comment: @Arjang that copy example shows how to copy the content of one file to another file. Which may be a lot heavier than to copy a file from one directory to another.

Answer (score 15):

If you are doing this in code, just use something like:

```
new File('copy.bin').bytes = new File('orig.bin').bytes
```

If this is for build-related code, this would also work, or use the Ant builder.

Note, if you are sure the files are textual you can use `.text` rather than `.bytes`.

Comment: While this is nice and simple, it loads the whole file into memory, which will fail for large files.

Comment: There are ways to stream it as well... `new File().withStream {}` - I went for the simplest approach.

Answer (score 13):

If it is a text file, I would go with:

```
  def src = new File('src.txt')
  def dst = new File('dst.txt')
  dst << src.text
```

Answer (score 12):

I prefer this way:

```
def file = new File("old.file")
def newFile = new File("new.file")
Files.copy(file.toPath(), newFile.toPath())
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer? And is there even a method that accepts Path and File?

Comment: File class has that method for a reason. This way is using such method (which is not being used by the accepted answer). In Groovy, File is already included while Path needs to be imported. If you mainly use Path, then the accepted answer is better, but if you use File this ways is more convenient IMHO, but you may think otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

To append to existing file :

```
def src = new File('src.txt')
def dest = new File('dest.txt')
dest << src.text
```

To overwrite if file exists :

```
def src = new File('src.txt')
def dest = new File('dest.txt')
dest.write(src.text)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using `AntBuilder` for such tasks. It's simple, consistent, 'battle-proven' and fun.

2nd approach is too OS-specific (Linux-only in your case)

3rd it too low-level and it eats up more resources. It's useful if you need to transform the file on the way: change encoding for example

4th looks overcomplicated to me... NIO package is relatively new in JDK.

In the end of the day, I'd go for 1st option. There you can switch from `copy` to `scp` task, without re-developing the script almost from scratch

Comment: You mean NIO2 (introduced in Java 7). NIO (New I/O) was introduced in Java 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way using platform independent groovy script. If anyone has questions please ask in the comments.

```
def file = new File("java/jcifs-1.3.18.jar")
this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(file.toURI().toURL())

def auth_server = Class.forName("jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication").newInstance("domain", "username", "password")
def auth_local = Class.forName("jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication").newInstance(null, "local_username", "local_password")

def source_url = args[0]
def dest_url = args[1]
def auth = auth_server

//prepare source file
if(!source_url.startsWith("\\\\"))
{
  source_url = "\\\\localhost\\"+ source_url.substring(0, 1) + "\$" + source_url.substring(1, source_url.length());
  auth = auth_local  
}
source_url = "smb:"+source_url.replace("\\","/");
println("Copying from Source -> " + source_url);
println("Connecting to Source..");

def source = Class.forName("jcifs.smb.SmbFile").newInstance(source_url,auth)
println(source.canRead());


// Reset the authentication to default
auth = auth_server

//prepare destination file
if(!dest_url.startsWith("\\\\"))
{
  dest_url = "\\\\localhost\\"+ dest_url.substring(0, 1) + "\$" +dest_url.substring(2, dest_url.length());
  auth = auth_local  
}

def dest = null
dest_url = "smb:"+dest_url.replace("\\","/");
println("Copying To Destination-> " + dest_url);
println("Connecting to Destination..");

dest = Class.forName("jcifs.smb.SmbFile").newInstance(dest_url,auth)
println(dest.canWrite());

if (dest.exists()){
  println("Destination folder already exists");
}
source.copyTo(dest);
```

Answer (score 0):

**For copying files in Jenkins Groovy**

**For Linux:**

```js
try {
 echo 'Copying the files to the required location'
 sh '''cd /install/opt/
 cp /install/opt/ssl.ks /var/local/system/'''     
 echo 'File is copied successfully'
}
catch(Exception e) {
 error 'Copying file was unsuccessful'
}



**For Windows:**
try {
 echo 'Copying the files to the required location'
 bat '''@echo off
 copy C:\\Program Files\\install\\opt\\ssl.ks C:\\ProgramData\\install\\opt'''    
 echo 'File is copied successfully'
}
catch(Exception e) {
 error 'Copying file was unsuccessful'
}
```