# Universal copy command for Windows and Linux

Tags: shell, cmd, copy

I was just curious that is there any universal command to copy files. Which should work for both Windows and Linux system.

I know Windows uses `copy` command and Linux uses `cp` command. But is there any universal command to do so.

Comment: No, there is no universal command. If you want to make a windows like version of unix, you could write a batch file called `cp.cmd` and modify it to behave like `cp` but with `copy` commands and put it in path, but that is similar to downloading tools like cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

If powershell is installed in your Windows OS,
then you can use the built-in command `cp` as well, just like Linux does.

Comment: Powershell has its own command prompt, you can start it like you would start cmd.exe

Comment: I just wanted to know if it is possible from command prompt itself.

Comment: The answer is no. Common commands are "copy" and "xcopy" for windows command prompt , whereas linux is "cp". There is no universal command between linux and windows

Answer (score 1):

UNIX/Linux, Mac, and Windows can all run PowerShell Core 6. https://github.com/powershell/powershell

The command is `Copy-Item`, but there are three (3) aliases. Using an alias at a command prompt is fine, but they should not be put into script files.

```
>Get-Alias -Definition Copy-Item

CommandType     Name
-----------     ----
Alias           copy -> Copy-Item
Alias           cp -> Copy-Item
Alias           cpi -> Copy-Item
```

Since there is no "universal" command, something will need to be installed on every machine except those that already have the command you choose to make "universal." At a minimum, it would be a .bat/.cmd script on Windows or a shell script on UNIX/Linux/Mac. Choosing to implement it in Python or any other language would require that language to be installed.

Comment: To copy a file, instead of installing Microsoft's useless response to bash, simply add alias in bash that also takes 'copy' on top of 'cp' to make a command work both ways.

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal command to do this, but you have several workarounds:

- use cygwin or msys on Windows to have the Linux equivalent commands on windows
- use Windows Powershell (partially compatible, but works for `cp`)
- provided that your environments all have python installed, write a python script that does what you want .

Comment: I am not familiar with python, I want to know if groovy can implement this.

Comment: I am not familiar with groovy, but it seems it can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049395/how-to-copy-files-in-groovy